# Nested subscribe that depends on outer subscribe response

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

Currently i have a code that looks like this:

TS:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.authService.getCurrentUser().subscribe((response) => {
      this.currentUser = response;
      const position = this.appService.searchPosition();
      const formData = this.appService.getFormData(this.candidateId);
      forkJoin([position, formData]).subscribe({
        next: (data) => {
          [this.positionList, this.myForm] = data;
          this.myForm.patchValue({
             // Initiating form with values from formData
             phoneNumber: formData.phoneNumber
          });
         
          // Here I want to add another service call to check for a status
          
          this.appService.checkStatus(formData.phoneNumber, this.candidateId).subscribe(
            response => {

               // Response here is a boolean
               if (response) {
                  this.status = true;
               }
            }
          )

          this.isLoading = false;
        },
        error: (err) => console.error(err),
      });
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<button *ngIf="status">Some Button</button>
```

The issue I am facing is that `this.status` does not update because the nested subscribe is fired  after the view got initiated with `this.isLoading = false`.

Putting `this.isLoading = false` inside nested subscribe is not an option because the view won't initiate at all.

How should I call a nested subscribe in this case so that `this.isLoading = false` works correctly here ?

Have tried `switchMap` and `mergeMap` as it was suggested in other threads. Didn't work, and I'm pretty sure it's because of how I tried to implement them.

This was my attempt:

```
this.authService.getCurrentUser().pipe(
 switchMap((user) => {
   this.currentUser = user

   // This call gets formData for next switchMap
   return this.appService.getFormData(this.candidateId);
  }
 ),
 switchMap((formData) => {

   // This call gets status
   reutrn this.appService.checkStatus(formData.phoneNumber, this.candidateId)
 })
).subscribe(data => {

   // Console log is not called and rest of the code doesn't work.
   console.log(data); 
 })
```

I know one of those is most likely the right answer for me, but I simply can't get to understand how should I use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are chaining unnecessary observables from the beginning, take a look at this:

```js
this.authService.getCurrentUser().subscribe(response => {
  this.currentUser = response;
  ...
  ...
})
```

The only purpose of `getCurrentUser()` is to store data in the class property `currentUser`, after that, the code that follows does not even use `currentUser` value, then why `searchPosition` and `getFormData` need to be embedded in this first `observable`? These two do not depend on the response from `getCurrentUser()`, so primarily, you could start handling the user separately with something like:

```js
// do not forget to handle the subscription
this.authService.getCurrentUser().subscribe(res => this.currentUser = res);
```

I see a few more things in your code that make me wonder the logic shown in this post, so I will try to figure out what you want to achieve. For handling the other observables, you could do it as the following:

```js
const position$ = this.appService.searchPosition();
const formData$ = this.appService.getFormData(this.candidateId);
const final$ = forkJoin([position$, formData$]);

final$.pipe(
  switchMap((res) => {
    const [positionData, formData] = res;
    this.positionList = positionData;
    this.myForm.get('phoneNumber').patchValue(formData.phoneNumber); 
    
    return this.appService.checkStatus(formData.phoneNumber, this.candidateId);
  })
).subscribe((response) => {
  this.isLoading = false;
  if (response) this.status = true;
})
```

Another alternative without using `forkJoin` could be as the following:

```js
this.appService.searchPosition().pipe(
  switchMap((response) => {
     this.positionList = response;
     return this.appService.getFormData(this.candidateId);
  }),
  switchMap((response) => {
    this.myForm.get('phoneNumber').patchValue(response.phoneNumber); 
    return this.appService.checkStatus(response.phoneNumber, this.candidateId);
  })
).subscribe((response) => {
  this.isLoading = false;
  if (response) this.status = true;
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. This code works great until this part
```.subscribe((response) => {
  this.isLoading = false;
  if (response) this.status = true;
})```

The subscribe doesn't fire and everything within it stays at its default values. Any ideas what might be the issue ?

Comment: are you sure the `subscribe` doesn't trigger? did you try console logging to see what the response is? I am pretty sure it works

Comment: Yes, that's why i am confused. Neither console.log or debugger doesn't trigger inside that subscribe.

Comment: I added another alternative without using Forkjoin

Comment: Unfortunately the result is still the same, for some reason i just can't get that `subscribe` to trigger.

Comment: Quick update: I think we have found the issue, it all came down to how our backend handles this one request. We decided that easiest solution would be to redo the backend part so that i get the `status` together with the form data response as a single object, that solves the issue of being dependent on the response from previous backend call. Nonetheless thank you for the answer, I'm pretty sure i will come back to `switchMap` and `mergeMap` a bit later to learn how to use them better.